# How to determine the result to be considered in the action of a rule based on a data matrix in a decision table of drools

Tags: matrix, drools, xls, rules, rule-engine

How can I write rules in drools given an array of data and making use of decision table

Entry

```
[
    {
        Caso: "Caso 1",
        Producto: "Producto1"
    },
    {
        Caso: "Caso 1",
        Producto: "Producto3"
    },
    {
        Caso: "Caso 3",
        Producto: "Producto2"
    }
]
```

Expected result

```
[
    {
        Caso: "Caso 1",
        Producto: "Producto1",
        resultado: true
    },
    {
        Caso: "Caso 1",
        Producto: "Producto3",
        resultado: false
    },
    {
        Caso: "Caso 3",
        Producto: "Producto2",
        resultado: false
    }
]
```

example of data to consider

```
        Producto1   Productto2  Producto3
Caso 1  true        false       false
Caso 2  false       true        false
Caso 3  false       false       true
```

The only thing I can think of is to handle it in the following way, but it makes me long to transcribe the matrix because it is very large, so I wonder if there is no way to implement the rule while keeping the previous format

[image]

Comment: your problem that it's taking a long time to write the data inside the excel? Inside the decision table there should be the logic, not the actual data.

Comment: @LucaMolteni The problem is how to write a decision table using a matrix as the "example of data to consider".

Comment: @LucaMolteni If I load the array "sample data to consider" into drools' working memory, do you have any ideas how I could write the rule? I think in the end I run into the same problem

Comment: @LucaMolteni What I want is to use the structure of an array as "sample data to consider"

Comment: Is your problem actually that when you have Caso _x_ and Producto _x_, you need to return true, false otherwise? because that is a single rule. Or an if-statement in Java. Just parse _x_ to an integer and compare. If that is not the case, I don't really understand what you are trying to do. You can't extrapolate data from a sample, but you can write rules for patterns.

Comment: On further thought, you can do what you're proposing with rule templates, but the input data isn't in JSON so that will have to be converted. And the output is DRL instead of decision tables.